# Does Tornado autoreload just restart the server?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I try to use autoreload option in Python server Tornado.
I've found in doc that autoreload automatically restarts the server: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/autoreload.html
But what if the server start for a long time? Every change will cause full reload? It's not what I want.
So is it right that autoreload option is not very suitable for servers that starts for a long time?

Comment: Autoreload feature is only meant to be used during development.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Of course I understand that the option is for development only. But what if the server starts long in development enviroment? Autoreload option just restart the server when observed files are changed, is it correct? Server is running, then I change the code and autoreload option just restarts the server as if I would restart it manually?

Comment: Yes, the whole server will restart. If you're trying to avoid long restart times, you can use [`add_reload_hook`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/autoreload.html#tornado.autoreload.add_reload_hook) to run a function before the restart happens. In that function, you can save your program's state (for example in [pickle format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)). Then, after the server restarts, you can load that state and avoid performing the long running task.

Comment: This is just an idea, but the exact solution will depend upon your problem and what you're actually trying to do.